# Mod rewrite rules doesnt work if url contains https:// in the middle

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url:

```
http://example.com/key/https://.pictureurl.jpg
```

to http://pictureurl.jpg

However this one doesn't work and I wonder why:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^key/https://(.*)$ $1 [R,L]
```

So it should end up getting redirected to http://pictureurl.jpg
However it doesnt't. It gets redirected to:

```
http://www.https.com/pictureurl.jpg
```

and this is one invalid url. Why is that and how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how your URLs can look like. Maybe: RewriteRule ^.*key/https://\.(.*)$ http://$2 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^key/https://\.(.*)$ //$1 [R,L]
```

I tested it [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) , and it seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that **`mod_rewrite` strips multiple slashes to a single slash** in `RewriteRule` pattern.

You can use a `RewriteCond` to match `https://` in your URI as in this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/key/https://(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache while testing this.